# How To Load Image Though URL in action script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, preloader

I have tested the code in action script 2.0 . it is working great but it     does not support GIF  so  i want it write in action script 3.0.
 But i have no idea in this.

```
 var current_loader: Number = 1;
 import flash.geom.*;
 var current_img: Number = 0;
 this.createEmptyMovieClip('img_01', 999);
 this.createEmptyMovieClip('img_02', 998);
 var loader: MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
 var listener: Object = new Object();

 listener.onLoadComplete = function (target_mc: MovieClip) {
     if (target_mc._name == 'img_01') {
         img_02._visible = false;
     } else {
         img_01._visible = false;
     }
     progress_bar.visible = true;
     current_loader.opaqueBackground = 0xFF0000;
 };

 var interval: Number = setInterval(load_image, 1000);

 function load_image() {
     loader.addListener(listener);
 }

 loader.loadClip("http://google/Example3", current_loader);
 current_loader = current_loader == 1 ? 2 : 1;
 current_img = current_img == images.length - 1 ? 0 : current_img + 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are simpler ways using straight as3 but this a robust way to load may file types with lots of great documentation. https://greensock.com/LoaderMax-AS3

Answer (score 3):

Very simple in as3: 
open Flash IDE, create new .fla file, select first frame, open 'actions (f9)' copy code.

Of course in AS3 it's better to use classes to put your code in. 
[image]

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://dummyimage.com/600x400/e000e0/fff.gif");
imageLoader.load(request);

addChild (imageLoader);

// and all possible listeners
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS,  httpStatusHandler);
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, initHandler);
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);

imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);


function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    trace("completeHandler: " + event);
}

function httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
    trace("httpStatusHandler: " + event);
}

function initHandler(event:Event):void {
    trace("initHandler: " + event);
}

function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
}

function openHandler(event:Event):void {
    trace("openHandler: " + event);
}

function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
    trace("progressHandler: bytesLoaded=" + event.bytesLoaded + " bytesTotal=" + event.bytesTotal);
}
```

see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#includeExamplesSummary

Comment: i am writing but can not getting any output... because i am  doing it first time. i am so confused after  writing codes in action script 2.0

Comment: What did you try? We can't help you when you only comment that you don't have any output.  I saw a little bug in my answer, so I update my answer and hope you will get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

i did like this .And its Working Perfectly.i think it is the simplest .

```
 package 
    {           
     import flash.display.Loader;            
     import flash.display.Sprite;             
     import flash.net.URLRequest;           
     import flash.utils.Timer;            
     import flash.events.TimerEvent;                
     import flash.events.Event;               

public class Example extends Sprite {
    public function Example() {
        var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);// 1 second
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,runMany);
        myTimer.start();
        function runMany(e:TimerEvent):void {
            var loader:Loader=new Loader();
            var url:String= "http://Google.Example3.com/latimage.php";
            loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
            addChild(loader);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But when i click the swf file..out side the player .it does not run ?